flutter Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:compileClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
Required by:
project :gradle > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.0
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
> repo.maven.apache.org
Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
Required by:
project :gradle > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.3.0
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom'.
> repo.maven.apache.org


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 13s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
flutter sdk 3.22 and
